# Different table layout when orientation is changed

Tags: android, layout

I have my table layout with severals rows and with two textViews in it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.blackess.smstestas.MyStatisticsActivity">


    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1">

        <TableRow>
            <TextView

                android:text="Celkem uskutečněných hovorů:"
                android:padding="3dip" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/allCalls"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="3dip" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView

                android:text="Celkem odesláno sms:"
                android:padding="3dip" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/allSms"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="3dip" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView

                android:text="Délka všech hovorů:"
                android:padding="3dip" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/allLenghtCalls"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="3dip" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView

                android:text="Celkový počet odeslaných sms:"
                android:padding="3dip" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/allCountSms"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="3dip" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView

                android:text="Nejdelší hovor:"
                android:padding="3dip" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/longestCall"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="3dip" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView

                android:text="Nejdelší sms:"
                android:padding="3dip" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/longestSms"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="3dip" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView

                android:text="Nejvolanější číslo:"
                android:padding="3dip" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mostCalled"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="3dip" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView

                android:text="Nejčastější příjemce zpráv:"
                android:padding="3dip" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mostSmsed"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="3dip" />
        </TableRow>


    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I´m setting up every single second TextView with some value. When i have my phone in horizontal position it looks good, but in clasic mode i can see only few digits of my value. How can i fix it?
Extra question: How can i let table layout fill relative layout to let my rows spread out on all screen. I have them only on top of my screen.

Answer (score 1):

Create a layout-port folder in your res folder of your app. Copy this xml and paste it into the layout-port folder. From there you can adjust the dimensions of your xml more freely without corrupting the landscape xml. Also rename your original layout folder to layout-land.